# What is the difference between reading session id, from cookie or request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

When you use session in `cookieless="false"` mode in `web.config`, it stores session id in a cookie value (I mean `aspnet_sessionId`). I want to know if by any reasons session id changes this cookie's value will update automatically or not?

And what is the difference between reading user session id by these two statements:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID
```

vs

```
Request.Cookies["Aspnet_sessionId"].Value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID
```

is a "shortcut" to

```
Request.Cookies["Aspnet_sessionId"].Value
```

BUt as you said, it isn't guaranteed to store the SessionID in a cookie. Based on the configuration of the application and the preferences of the client, the SessionID can be also a GET-Parameter.

Therefore you should use the `Session.SessionID` to make sure that you'll always retrieve it correctly.